# Problem with displaying information from the controller on view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Good day!
I am using asp.net mvs-5. I try to output information from json that I get in the controller (I store the variables in the container)

```
DataContainer.Add(new SlaData
            {
                issuesCount = DeserializedResponse.total,
                issueCreateDate = DeserializedResponse.issues.Min(x => x.fields.created)
            });

        return DataContainer;
```

through the API I get such json:

```
[
    {
        "issuesCount": 129,
        "issueCreateDate": "2018-11-15T09:51:01+07:00"
    }
]
```

I wrote a function in javascript, I want to display information from these variables in a table, tell me what I did wrong?
as a result, I have an empty table

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SlaPage</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" cols="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>issueCreateDate</th>
            <th>issuesCount</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("DataContainer", function (data) {
            var DataContainer_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                DataContainer_data += '<tr>';
                DataContainer_data += '<td>' +value.issueCreateDate+ '</td>';
                DataContainer_data += '<td>' +value.issueCount+ '</td>';
                DataContainer_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#data_table').append(DataContainer_data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That data you say you are getting back from the api is XML not JSON

Comment: @majita, it was json, my google chrome give me xml-file, editet start massage

Answer (score 0):

As @majita mentioned it, you get a XML structure, but you want to have a JSON structure. So you can use for example:

1) [JSON.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) and its `SerializeXmlNode`. Here is an example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm

2) You can send it to a (online) converter.

Comment: hi! 
I accidentally received a response from the API in xml using google chrome, in fact I get json, I edited the initial message

Comment: Try to do error handling and debugging. Debug through your code, check the `data` Ajax/GetJSON on `success` and `error`, do `console.log(kex + ": " value);`. As a beginner try to go step by step through your code to learn what is wrong and much more important why it is wrong and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding direct url to getJSON field

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:65265/API/Sla", function (data) {
            var Sla_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                Sla_data += '<tr>';
                Sla_data += '<td>' + value.issuesCount + '</td>';
                Sla_data += '<td>' + value.issueCreateDate + '</td>';
                Sla_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#sla_table').append(Sla_data);
        });
    });
```